# How to detect if my library is running with React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a native library that can be used by react native app or traditional native app. Inside of my library, I want to check if this native library is running in react native environment or not.

Any one has suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you just try to import the package in the js file. If the import statement doesn't through an error and you are able to invoke the functions of that library means your library is running.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed! but I want to do this in my native library which is in swift or java, maybe I can do similar thing?